# Maui Hybrid preload data before rendering first page

Tags: dependency-injection, maui-blazor

My Maui hybrid app needs to check if a user is logged in order to fetch user specific data while first page is rendering.

I tried to use CreateWindow event on App.xaml.cs to execute preloading tasks but Dependency Injected services don't seem to be available at this stage.

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider is a service overriding AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() to authenticate the user if a valid token is present on Maui SecureStorage.

How could I execute some code at startup which may use Dependency Injected services?

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [Inject] CustomAuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

        window.Created += (s, e) =>
        {
            _ = PreloadTasks();
        };

        return window;
    }

    public async Task PreloadTasks()
    {
        var state = await authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        if (state.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //preload user specific data while Ui is rendering
        }
    }
}
```

My Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(s => s.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());
return builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the instance which you have registered in the container, you could try using ServiceProvider:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
...
#if ANDROID
    serviceProvider = MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
     serviceProvider =  MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#elif WINDOWS
     serviceProvider =  MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services;
#endif
    
var authStateProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)) as CustomAuthenticationStateProvider;
```

Another way：
Since IServiceProvider is also in DI container, so this might be easier:

```
public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new AppShell();
   
    var authStateProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)) as CustomAuthenticationStateProvider;
}
```

Hope it works for you.